# Adding HTTPS to Embarcadero Community Edition [Delphi] V11

Tags: delphi, https, ssl-certificate

Using Embarcadero Community Edition V11.3 (Alexandria). All testing being performed on internal LAN, as ISP has ports 80, 443 blocked. Goal is to have it working before exposing to the internet.  Have generated certificate files ( fullchain.pem, privkey.pem, chain.pem, cert.pem - actually they are symlinks ) from Let's Encrypt.
Generating test app   File/New/Other/Web/Web Server Application/Windows/Stand-alone console application/HTTPS/
... presents boxes to fill in Certificate File Name, Key File Name, Key file password and Root certificate file name
... TRY TO fill in directory path to fullchain.pem, privkey.pem and leave the last 2 boxes empty.  Popup message "fullchain.pem  You don't have permission to open this file. Contact the file owner or an administrator to obtain permission."

The pem files' ownership cannot be changed, the Security Settings say "Unable to display current owner" even though ownership of subdirectories are changed to Administrators.

If anyone else has used Embarcadero software to add HTTPS to their app, I would sure like to know if there is an alternative method.

Tried to fill in boxes with file names, rejected with error message

Comment: Setting permissions on the directories containing symlinks has no effect on permissions to the underlying files. The file permissions come from the underlying files and where they are located and not from the symlink or where the symlink is located. Set permissions on the actual files to something that allows access.

Comment: Just to clarify: does the popup message appear while filling in the fields in the Wizard for the Stand-alone console application? Or at run time of the generated console app?

Comment: The popup messages appear while filling in the fields in the Wizard.  I never get far enough to generate the code for the console app.

Comment: Found an "archive" directory which contains the pem files.  Could not change the security. Copied the pem files to another directory for which I have total ownership.  Now get "Error connecting with SSL.  EOF was observed that violates the protocol".  The TLS drivers are located in the first directory of the path.  I know the drivers are being picked up from here because trying to move the files out while the IDE is open gives a "file in use" error.  I believe the drivers are for TLS 1.3.